# Adjust the brightness level of touch bar

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, touch-bar

I can't find anyway to adjust brightness level of touch bar on my mbp 2017 with macOS High Sierra. Perhaps it can be changed by adjusting values in SMC?

I have a different hardware model and macOS version so I asked another question. Please tell me if this is a duplicate question with [How can I adjust Touch Bar brightness?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306941/how-can-i-adjust-touch-bar-brightness).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I adjust Touch Bar brightness?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306941/how-can-i-adjust-touch-bar-brightness)

Comment: As far as I know the brightness level cannot be changed, the level is adjusted with the sensor located in the display (near to the camera). This question can be marked as dup of the one pointed by you.