# Is there a way to set the ambient light sensor's value?

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

I have a 2018 MacBook Pro with Touch Bar. The said Touch Bar is flickering from time to time (to the point it hurts my eyes) and does not even light up the rest of the time. It looks like the problem is coming from the hardware but after looking thru a lot of documentation and experimenting a lot it looks like when I expose the ambient light sensor to a flashlight the motherboard is sending more power to the Touch Bar's screen and the flickering stops.

Therefore, I am trying to find a way to set the ambient light sensor's value to something that would stop the screen from flickering. I do not know if this is even possible but I do not have the money or the competencies to fix the bad hardware. Sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: Are you covering your camera? Apparently that's where the sensor is. Related question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/306941/151404

Comment: Yep that's where it's located. I wasnt covering it, i was exposing it to lot of light using my phone's flashlight which stopped the flickering but this isnt viable fixing mehtod cause i have to hold my phone pointing the sensor :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no built-in way of setting the readout of the ambient light sensor.

To further complicate things, it is very difficult to "hack" such a setting in. The Touch Bar runs on its own processor with its own operating system and application code - completely separate from the ordinary macOS operating system.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i abandoned and just covered it with a sticker since it seems like their is no solution and never will to this problem :'(