# MacBook Pro 13 inch 2019, Touchbar flicker always

Tags: macbook-pro, flickr

I have MacBook Pro 2019 and My Touch Bar flickering always, what should I do?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/445593/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-ambient-light-sensors-value